# two column full height layout expands to contain content

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I've tried this a bunch of ways from using javascript to equalize the heights of the columns but it's messy and causes other issues.

I've tried pure css but all the solutions I've found have one draw back or another.

The most popular one seems to be to involve

```
body, html { height:100%;}
.col{width:50%; height:100%; float:left;}

<body>
<div class="col left">1st col
    <div class="bigdiv">yo</div>
    <div class="bigdiv">yo</div>
    <div class="bigdiv">yo</div>
</div>
<div class="col right">2nd col</div>
```

but this doesn't stretch if one of the columns is longer than the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/8nAA4/1/

There must be an easy way to do this and I must be being stupid but I've been trying different methods for a couple of days and it's doing my head in.

php, javascript, html all simple. css still confuses me!

Comment: This is actually a very difficult problem that has vexed designers for ever.  When you use `height:100%`, it sets the height to the height of the parent element, in this case the body, which is going to be the height of the viewport. There are a few different solutions to the problem as you have already noticed.  Google "css holy grail" and pick the best one for your situation. I like @Oriol's below.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
body{
    display: table;
}
.col{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8nAA4/2/)